# Power series of $f(x)=\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-x}}$

Tags: combinatorics, power-series, problem-solving

How do I find the power series form of $\,f(x)\,$:

$$\displaystyle f(x)=\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-x}}$$

I tried to multiply the fraction by $\,\dfrac{1+x}{1+x}\,$ but it didn't help...

Comment: are you allowed to use the taylor series?

Comment: nope, no taylor series

Comment: A Taylor Series is a type of power series and that seems like what you are asking for because "power series" by itself is rather generic. In fact, you are probably are asking for the Maclaurin series representation of $ f(x) $, i.e. $ f(x) = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty a_n x^n $.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try writing it as $ f(x) = \sqrt{ 1- x^2 } \times 1/(1-x) $  . Then write $ 1/(1-x) $ as a geometric series and the other term can be expanded using binomial theorem. Hope that helps.

Comment: Of course $ |x|< 1$ for this to hold, that would be radius of convergence of the series, I think.